# Sign out specific user with Devise in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have Devise for user authentication.
I want to sign out a user with a specific id.

in my controller

```
  def exit
    @user = User.find(5)
    sign_out(@user) # this line here signs out the current_user   
  end
```

The sign out command of devise, even though I pass the @user, it signs out the current_user.
How can I select a user from the database and sign him out with the devise commands?

Comment: Are you talking about signing a user out in tests or in your development / production environment?

Comment: what is the purpose? are you sure about the `@user` session is set

Comment: See the [`devise rememberable module`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/rememberable.rb).

Answer (score 8):

I am assuming this is part of some admin module, where you want to sign out a particular user.

However, this is *not* easy to solve. Whether or not a user is signed in or not is stored in the session. So to sign out another user, you would have to have access to its session.

Note: afaik the `sign_out` method only works in the current session, or maybe through warden (do not know warden well enough) it could extend to all sessions this current server has ever touched. However: if you use passenger, or some form of rails server cluster (which is pretty common), afaik this will not work. I would be interested to hear otherwise, with some explanation :) The `sign_out` uses the given parameter to determine the scope to sign out from in (afaik) the current session.

So what we generally did was add a kind of emergency button to sign out all users: which destroys all sessions. Note this is of course only possible if you use some database or document-store backed session-store.

Alternatively you could open all sessions, and look for the correct session (for your user), and then destroy those sessions.

To read data from a specific session in stored in activerecord, you can write the following:

```
@session = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all( "SELECT * FROM sessions WHERE session_id = '#{sess_id}'" )
Marshal.load(ActiveSupport::Base64.decode64(@session.data))
```

There are alternative approaches:

- use `Timeoutable` module, and force a timeout for a user?
- if you use `Rememberable` you could do `@user.forget_me`, but I am not sure that this actually affects the current session?

Answer (score 0):

from the device api doc http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_out-instance_method the sign_out(@user) method should works. Is it possible that the current_user by chance has the id 5?