# Sign out a devise user from a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my application, I need to sign out specific users from time to time. And I need to do it from the interface or from a sidekiq worker. So I would like to create a `sign_out` method in my `user` model.

I saw in the documentation that devise provides a `sign_out` method but only in the controller. Is there a way to access to this method from a model or something similar.

Thanks

Comment: What about add "force_logged_out" field to user and then log out in the controller next session?

Answer (score 5):

You need to read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24388643/4269732 first.

If I was to implement this behavior then I would have added a column in User Model like `expire_at_next_request?` 
Then just check this value in before_filter and logout the user if this is true.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :logout_if_requested

  def logout_if_requested
    if current_user && current_user.expire_at_next_request?
      current_user.update_attributes(:expire_at_next_request=>false)
      sign_out current_user
      redirect_to :new_session_path
    end
  end
```

Comment: This adds IO overhead to every request processed by the web app. Seems overkill.