# How can I make specific user(not current_user) sign out on rails-devise website?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to know how I can make specific user(not current_user) sign out.

I saw this http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Controllers/SignInOut#sign_out-instance_method and maked this code.

```
def kick_admin
  user = User.find params[:user_id]
  user.admin = false
  user.save
  sign_out user #want to kick him. 
end
```

But it does not make that user sign out but make me(current_user) signed out.
What is the right way to use the sign_out method?

I checked this answer([Sign out specific user with Devise in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387605/sign-out-specific-user-with-devise-in-rails/24388643)) but it was not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do this is create a new attribute in the User table, call it `force_sign_out`.

```
def kick_admin
  user = User.find params[:user_id]
  user.update_attributes(admin: false, force_sign_out: true)
end
```

And have a before action in ApplicatonController so that if the user attempts any activity he's signed out

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_action :check_if_force_sign_out

  def check_if_force_sign_out
    return unless current_user.force_sign_out
    current_user.update_attributes(force_sign_out: false) # reset for non-admin log in
    sign_out
    redirect_to root_path
  end

end
```

Comment: Was just about to post something similar to this. Nice solution!

Comment: Possible improvement on the kick - `user.update_attributes(admin: false, force_sign_out: true)`